# how to view the page through the admin panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

a resource documents and the appropriate controller:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @documents = Document.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end

  def admin_index
    @documents = Document.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    render layout: "admin" 
  end  

  def show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  end

  def admin_show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    render layout: "admin" 
  end  

  ....
  ....
end
```

a 2 layouts:

```
application.html.erb, 
admin.html.erb
```

the controller index lists the documents in the public section (application.html.erb).
admin_index controller displays a list of documents in the closed part of the site (admin.html.erb).

in the public part of the site I can look any document by clicking on 'show':

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
    <%= document.title %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', document %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that in a closed part of the site I did not get to see any document by clicking the link below:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', document %>
```

a problem that throws me a page of a particular document, but the layout: application.html.erb, and I need a layout: admin.html.erb

routes:

```
Testpager::Application.routes.draw do
  get "admin/index"
  resources :news, only: [:index, :show]

  resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]

  get "contacts/index"
  get "services/index"
  get "index/index"
  get "admin/index"
  get "admin/documents" => 'documents#admin_index'
  get "admin/documents/:id" => 'documents#admin_show'

  root 'index#index'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no difference in the link you've created with the `link_to` helper in your `index.html.erb` and `admin_index.html.erb`, so let's address that first.

Change your `admin_show` route in your `routes.rb` to:

```
get 'admin/documents/:id', to: 'documents#admin_show', as: 'admin_document'
```

Now change the `link_to` in your `admin_index.html.erb` to this:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', admin_document_path(document) %>
```

That should do it.

#### Side note

The way you've set up the 'public' and 'admin' parts of your site seem odd. I would personally create an `admin` namespace and a separate `DocumentsController` in that namespace. You'll have to change your `routes.rb`, create an admin controller, view and layout if you want this.

Add the documents resource to the admin namespace instead of the admin routes you've already added:

```
...

namespace :admin do
  resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]
end

resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]

...
```

Create a `app/controllers/admin/documents_controller.rb` file and move the `admin_*` methods from your original controller to that one and also move the `admin_*.html.erb` views to `app/views/admin/*.html.erb`.

Now, last but not least move your `app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb` file to `app/views/layouts/admin/application.html.erb`. That should do it.

Note that you've got to use a module in your admin controller:

```
module Admin
  class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```